# Parsing error after moving wordpress site from online to wamp

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I moved a wordpress site from online to offline, what I did is as following:
Export the database.
Import the database to wamp.
Copy all of the website's files into a new folder.
Edit wp-config to match the db name and username.

Now, at first, I had an internal 500 error when I tried to access the website,
I replaced the htaccess file with a default one from wordpress, now I'm getting a parsing error from header.php which looks correct.

I tried to rename the header.php just to see what happens but it keeps on outputting the same error, like the problem isn't really connected to that file.
This is the exact error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp64\www\feincook\wp-content\themes\feincook\header.php on line 169

Here's the header.php code for you to see:

```
 ?php
 /**
 * The Header for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
  * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
   * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0   
   */
 ?><!DOCTYPE html>
 <!--[if IE 7]>
 <html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8]>
 <html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8) ]><!-->
 <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <!--<![endif]-->
 <head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js">      </script>
<![endif]-->

<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?  >/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
 <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/bjqs.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" media="print" href="<?php echo   get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/print.css" />
 <?php if (is_single()) {
    global $post;
    $cat='';
    $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
    foreach ( $cats as $c ) {
        $cat .= $c->category_nicename.' ';
        $catClass = 'category-'.$cat;
    }
     } ?>


 <!-- //Facebook Pixel -->
 <script>(function() {
 var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
 if (!_fbq.loaded) {
 var fbds = document.createElement('script');
 fbds.async = true;
 fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
_fbq.loaded = true;
 }
 _fbq.push(['addPixelId', '862151620502417']);
  })();
 window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
 window._fbq.push(['track', 'PixelInitialized', {}]);
 </script>
 <noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"   src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=862151620502417&amp;ev=PixelInitialized" />   </noscript>

 </head>

   <body <?php body_class($catClass); ?>>
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new  Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)   [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })   (window,document,'script','//www.googleanalytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-55236663-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=430603427072800";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="headerWrapper">
    <?php $getTheSwatch = get_post_meta($post->ID,'colorSwatch',true); ?>
    <div class="header-main swatch<?php echo $getTheSwatch; ?>">
        <div id="site-header">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"  title="Feincook - Let's cook better!">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/headerLogo.jpg"  alt="Feincook - Let's cook better!">
    </a>
    <div class="blogBaloon"></div>
  </div>
        <div class="socialLinksHolder">
            <ul class="socialLinks">
                <li><a class="facebookLink"  href="https://www.facebook.com/FeinCook" target="_blank"></a></li>
                <li><a class="youtubeLink"  href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe3HkTlwmXCmg-CmUVZwSqQ" target="_blank">  </a></li>
                <li><a class="instagramLink" href="http://instagram.com/feincook" target="_blank"></a></li>
                <li><a class="mailLink" href="mailto:<?php echo 'info@';echo  'feincook.co.il'; ?>" target="_blank"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<? php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
                <label>
            <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
            <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="חפש באתר" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
            </label>
<input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
            </form>
            <?php
 global $userdata;
 get_currentuserinfo();
 if($userdata->user_level>9){?> <a class="hiddenLink" href="<?php echo     home_url( '/' ); ?>?page_id=290">איך להכניס ולערוך תכנים  באתר?</a> <?php }
?>
        </div>

    <div class="mobileHide">
    <input type="radio" id="mobileClose" name="mobileButton">
    <label class="menuBotton" for="mobileClose"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="mobileOpen" name="mobileButton">
    <label class="menuBotton" for="mobileOpen"></label>
        <div class="mobileMenu">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'main cat menu' ) ); ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( $menuARG ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="navLinksHolder">
            <?php $menuARG = array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'menu_class' => 'nav-menu',
                'before' => '<span class="beforeItem"></span>',
            ); ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( $menuARG ); ?>
            <a style="display:none;" class="myRecipesLink" href="">המתכונים שלי</a>
            <?php global $userdata;
                get_currentuserinfo();
                if($userdata->user_level>9){ ?>
<a class="menuEditLink" href="http://www.feincook.co.il/wp-admin/nav-   menus.php?action=edit&menu=5" target="_blank">עריכת תפריט</a>
 <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <?php
            if ( is_home() ) {
             $catMenuLocal = homepage;
        } else {
             $catMenuLocal = regular;
            }
        if(is_category()){};
        if(is_single()){
            $cats = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
            $thecatid = $cats[0];
        };
        ?>


            <div class="currentCircle"></div>
        <div class="mainCatMenu cat<?php echo $thecatid; ?> " id="<?php echo $catMenuLocal ?>">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'main cat menu' ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- / .headerWrapper -->
<div id="main" class="site-main swatch<?php meta('colorSwatch'); ?>">
```

Comment: Your header.php dump has only 165 lines...

Comment: Indeed, like I said, it didn't matter if I deleted the whole file, the source of the problem is not within it and I figured it out and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was a plugin named w3-cache, for anyone that uses it and has encountered this sort of problem, disabling it (renaming the actual plugin folder or deleting it) solves the problem.